# get relative position after GetCursorPos in CLR?

Tags: c#, c++, c, mouseevent, clr

So as of now, I've managed to successfully get the x and y coordinates.

Inside the panel code.

```
   POINT cursorPos;
                GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
                int x;
                int y;
                x = cursorPos.x;
                y = cursorPos.y;
                cout << x << endl;
                cout << y << endl;
```

**However**, the x and y coordinate that I got is global, aka, not within a panel that I want to get my coordinates from.

I do understand that ClientToScreen is required to change the x and y coordinate to its relative placing, but how do i do that in **C++/CLR?**

Because ClientToScreen requires a handle, which is not introduced in C++/CLR (Pardon me if im wrong about this point). Thanks :)

Update: I tried casting my panel into a hwnd, but still its not working.

```
HWND hwnd = static_cast<HWND>(this->panel1->Handle.ToPointer());
```

Comment: Assuming you're using WinForms, searching for handle in the panel class would get you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx. However, I doubt you need to ask for the cursor position. You should be told through events.

Comment: hi @chris, For example, in the class: I see the following : this->panel1->Paint += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler(this, &MazeGUI::panel1_Paint); 

Does that mean the handle for this case is panel1->Paint?

Comment: No, `Paint` is an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_events(v=vs.110).aspx) that is being subscribed to, like you should probably be doing with mouse events. When you get notified of a mouse event, the position is included.

Comment: @chris sigh, I feel so stupid. lol, I definitely know that panel1 must be included as an handle, but apparently it doesn't work (ClientToScreen(panel1, &Cursorpos). ahhh the fustration.

Comment: Use the panel's PointToClient() method instead.  And use the Point type, not POINT.  And Cursor::Position, not GetCursorPos().  And the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get global coordinates because `GetCursorPos()` is relative to the screen. To convert it to Application coordinates, you simply use `ScreenToClient()` on the POINT structure filled by `GetCursorPos()`.

Check the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What about the hwnd part? I can't figure the way out even if I tried converting panel into handle. It doesn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are doing it in c++/clr not native, so I don't think this will work since a panel is a .NET object not a win32. I think you are doing it wrong for using GetCursorPos() on a managed window. There must be set of API's from .NET that does this

Comment: Alright, I found it. I shall work my way up. Thanks.